# RHEL 7 and Tomcat 8 SSL 443

Tags: tomcat, https, redhat

I am attempting to use port 443 for Tomcat to bind to the OS (RHEL 7)

From what I have read, Tomcat needs special permission to bind to ports lower than 1024, which is ok.

In my current env, if I change the connector from 8080, to just 80, I am able to hit my Tomcat server just fine :

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

http://localhost

When I do it with https, it redirects me to a blank page. (This page is present and blank regardless if tomcat is working or not) Note, I change both of the connectors to point to 443 like so.

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="cools"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Then I tried ip tables, with the following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

However, the default apache page does not load either. I am stumped as to what I can try next. Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First Check Firewall to enable port 443.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

This will show what ports are opened. If port 443 is not execute this command.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```

Reload firewall to take effect

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now check. If not worked disabled the selinux temporary

```
setenforce 0
```

Then check. After disabling selinux, if its worked. Problem with selinux context